# Serilog with .net core web api 2.2

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, asp.net-core, docker-compose, serilog

I am trying to use the `ElasticSearchSink` for `Serilog`. I have `docker-compose` file to launch `ElasticSearch`, `Kibana` and `.NET Core 2.2 Web API`.

Here's the code in `Configure` in `Startup.cs`

```
  public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        {
            if (env.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            var elasticUri = Configuration["ElasticConfiguration:Uri"];

            var logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
                .Enrich.FromLogContext()
                .WriteTo.Elasticsearch(new ElasticsearchSinkOptions(new Uri(elasticUri))
                {
                    AutoRegisterTemplate = true
                });

            loggerFactory.AddSerilog();

            Log.Logger = logger.CreateLogger();

            app.UseMvc();
        }
```

`appsettings.json` is

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Debug",
      "System": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Information"
    }
  },

  "AllowedHosts": "*",

  "ElasticConfiguration": {
    "Uri": "http://localhost:9200/"
  }
}
```

I can hit `localhost:9200` and `Kibana` also launches fine. But there is no data in `Kibana`. I don't see any error but I was expecting some data in the `ES` and `Kibana`.

The controller class is:

```
public class AuthenticationController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly ILogger<AuthenticationController> _logger;

        public AuthenticationController(ILogger<AuthenticationController> logger)
        {
            _logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("token")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> ValidateToken([FromBody] AuthenticateRequest request)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation($"ValidateToken: request received with {request}");
            return Ok(new AuthenticateRespose
            {
                Token = "testing", Duration = 0
            });
        }
    }
```

I can hit that endpoint from `Postman` both in running from `docker-compose` or just debugging with `Docker` in `VS`.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that `http://localhost:9200/` is correct? Are the different Docker containers running on a shared network interface? It they aren't you probably should try to change this into `http://<service name>:9200/` where `service name` is the name you give the Serilog container in the Docker compose file.

Comment: yes it works if i use any browser, not sure when the .net core is run in docker if it can  have access to that or not